# charging 10Ah li-ion batteries in parallel

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

i'm trying to charge a 5Ah single cell li-ion battery using bq24090 charger controller (up to 1A fast charge current) in parallel with a current boosting circuit. Overall controller should supply fast charge current at 0.5C rate(2.5A), theoretically. Which idea does make sense if i try to charge 4 of these li-ion  batteries?

option 1: using 4 distinct charger controller as described for each one of the batteries

option 2: using single more advanced charger controller such as bq24600 (up to 10A fast charge current) and supplying 4 parallel batteries from that single output of the controller.

Thank you.

**datasheets**

**bq24090**    http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24090.pdf

**bq24600**    http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24600.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to charge batteries in parallel, for any battery chemistry. If the batteries (cells) are in different states-of-charge, they may try to charge each other without any current-limiting between them. Better to charge them individually, so that the charger can sense each cell individually.

Cells that are permanently connected in parallel are usually assumed to all have the same state-of-charge.

Comment: Not really, you can use shunt resistors and FETs to bleed energy out of cells that reach the charge terminal voltage earlier than others. Obviously a bit of complex circuitry involved here, and each cell needs to be individually monitored, but it works.

Comment: Actually that may be for series connections only, my bad. I'm sure there is a way using diodes and FETs though.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. your answer leads to another question in my mind Mr.John. if state of charge of each batteries could be sensed through sense resistors and charge current is controlled by some switch mechanism through uP according to that state-of-charge, is it still not wise to charge batteries in parallel (just asking for brainstorming)? Thanks again

Comment: @vilacikovski Yes, if the charger can sense state-of-charge for individual cells, that's OK. But if the cells are truly in parallel (no intervening sense resistors, diodes, etc.) I don't think there's any way to know individual state-of-charge. I was thinking of cells that had been discharged individually and then connected in parallel solely for charging.

Comment: so, one last question. Is parallelling battery charger with a linear regulator to boost charge current a good idea? Thanks.

Comment: @vilacikovski No, it's not a good idea becuse the linear regulator will go on supplying current to the battery, after the charger has stopped. The charger will stop charging when the battery is full, i.e. when it reaches 4.2V in the case of Li-ion. The linear regulator will not stop and will overcharge the Li-ion battery. This is a very dangerous thing to do, and can cause the battery to catch fire. Much better to get a bigger charger.

Comment: if that is the only problem, my plan is to control the linear regulator according to current&voltage on the battery. Does it also make no sense? @JohnHonniball

Comment: @vilacikovski If you're going to control the linear regulator in that manner, you're really building another charger. You might as well use just one charger with a big enough current output to charge the batteries at the rate you want. Havng two chargers (effectively) connected to the battery at the same time may lead to unwanted interactions.

Comment: thanks for your kind responses and patience @JohnHonniball . You clarify many question in my mind about charging issue.